# How to view own posts to a site in ascending order of time of recent activity associated with a post?

Tags: support, sorting

I would like know for I can view my posts in reverse order of user activity. I am aware of "user:me".

Comment: You could write a SEDE query to return them in that order. Would that do?

Comment: There is no way to reverse the sort order, anywhere in Stack Exchange. So SEDE is pretty much the only option we have.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/557744) is a SEDE query which shows your posts, ordered by the last activity on the entire question (where your post is one of the answers). Oldest posts are shown first. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/557741) is a simpler one where the last activity is on the post itself.

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 p.Id AS [Post Link], 
    CASE
      WHEN q.LastActivityDate IS NULL THEN p.LastActivityDate
      ELSE q.LastActivityDate
    END 'Last activity',
  p.Body
  FROM posts AS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN posts AS q
    ON p.ParentId = q.Id
  WHERE p.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
  ORDER BY
    CASE
      WHEN q.LastActivityDate IS NULL THEN p.LastActivityDate
      ELSE q.LastActivityDate
    END ASC
```

As always, note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, and you're <s>free</s> encouraged to make your own query based on the ones the community provides.